# How to use ObjectMapper to read in an Json format to an Object which contains String and List<String>

Tags: java, json, list, objectmapper

I have an Object like this:

```
public class Marketplace {
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private List<String> supportedLanguages;
}
```

and I have an input Json format String like this:

```
{
"name":"US",
"id":1,
"supportedLanguages":{"en_US", "es_US"}
}
```

I tried something like this first but failed:

```
objectMapper.readValue(marketplaceInJsonString, Marketplace.class);
```

Then I tried something like this but still failed:

```
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readValue(marketplaceInJsonString, JsonNode.class);

Marketplace marketplace = new Marketplace(jsonNode.get("name").asText()), jsonNode.get("id").asInt(), jsonNode.findValuesAsText("supportedLanguages"));
```

I think the key problem here is that I don't find the correct way to map supportedLanguages as a List of String.

And is there any format problem of the Json String input?

Please help, and really appreciate.

Comment: is if feasible to change `"supportedLanguages":{"en_US", "es_US"}` to `"supportedLanguages":["en_US", "es_US"]`? because json is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json string is not valid json
change it to

```
{
  "name": "US",
  "id": 1,
  "supportedLanguages": [
    "en_US",
    "es_US"
  ]
}
```

Testing code:

```
String marketplaceInJsonString = "{\"name\":\"US\",\"id\":1,\"supportedLanguages\":[\"en_US\",\"es_US\"]}";
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Marketplace marketplace = objectMapper.readValue(marketplaceInJsonString, Marketplace.class);
System.out.println(marketplace);
```

//output

```
Marketplace(name=US, id=1, supportedLanguages=[en_US, es_US])
```